# Recommend me a resource question should be closed. But with some bounty not?

Tags: discussion, bounties, close-reasons

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086253/book-to-introduce-functional-world-to-c-sharp-developer) asks to recommend a book to introduce functional world to the C# developer.

Such a question without a bounty would be closed because of:

1. opinion based open end discussion. There is no "right" answer for it.
2. asking for some resources - this time it's a book.

Or do you think this question is SO conforming?

*Update:*
I have flagged it with

> It is opinion based open end discussion. Thats why is off topic. Also cause for "recommen be resource" (in this case book) question. Any other such a question without bounty would be closed after flagging it

*cannot edit flag text anymore )

*Update2:*

Its on hold already =)

Comment: Plese dont edit quotes =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's all you have to do - flag the question. A moderator will run across it eventually and can manually remove the bounty from the question, as well as close it once that's done. I've gone ahead and done both. This question clearly isn't on-topic for our site.